# How to select all children except first and last with CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

How would I select all the children in a table except for the first and last? I've tried this, but it ends up selecting all children that aren't first and all children that aren't last, which ends up being all children:

```
table.programs tr td:not(:first-child), table.programs tr td:not(:last-child) {
}
```

I want all children that are neither first nor last. How can I do this?

Comment: related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403129/combining-not-selectors-in-css

Comment: This one's more closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033299/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-css-shorthand-for-all-elements-except-the-first-l (probably even a dupe)

Answer (score 115):

Use two `:not()` selectors combined, thereby referring to elements that match both of them, i.e. to elements that match neither of the selectors used as operands of `:not()`:

```
table.programs td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
```

Comment: @FrankV, you misunderstood the other question and its answer. The question refers to chained `:not()` selectors but asks whether there is an alternative.

Comment: td+td:not(:last-child)

Answer (score 6):

The jQuery solution is fine, but if you want to do it in pure CSS I'd suggest you to apply the rules to the whole table and then *reset* them for the first and last children. i.e:

```
table.programs tr td { 
  /* your rules here */
}

table.programs tr:first-child td:first-child, 
table.programs tr:last-child td:last-child {
  /* reset your rules here */
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xyzzy/q9Epw/1/)

Comment: I think your answer is the best, because it's cross-browser, so 7,8(still actual), windows phones with old ie supports it.

Answer (score 4):

like this.

```
li:nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(n+2) { background: red; }
```

for your requirement

```
table.programs tr td:nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(n+2) { /* Your Style */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you:

```
table.programs tr td:not(:first-child,:last-child)
```

Comment: Well, he sad CSS selectors (which jQuery also uses). But considering the syntax he posted, the point is moot =).

Comment: Note, if you're using this in CSS, this is not supported in some older browsers. I would consider giving all your first and last elements `first` and `last` classes if possible.

Comment: jQuery uses a non-standard version of `:not()`, so while this is a valid jQuery selector, it is not a valid CSS selector (yet), so it won't work in a stylesheet. That's when the distinction between "CSS selector" and "jQuery selector" (from @Barmar's comment) becomes very important. See [What's the difference in the :not() selector between jQuery and CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css)

Comment: Exactly. jQuery's selectors are a superset of CSS selectors, although many of them are in CSS4.

Answer (score 1):

It works in this way

```
    table.programs tr td:nth-child(1n+2):not(:last-child)
```