# How to access inner elements of external components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have an external `Select` react component which in turn render `li` tags.
I want to style all `li` except the first one with `margin-left` of 20px;

Below is the code:

```
const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
  li {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
`
```

Any idea why this is not working or another way to do this?

Comment: your code will style all li elements inside the Select component. If you want to exclude the first li you'll have to add a css rule/selector. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033299/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-css-shorthand-for-all-elements-except-the-first-l)

Comment: your question is a bit unclear. Is the `margin-left: 20px;` applied properly, and are you wondering how to exclude the first li? Or is your style not applied at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work, but depending on how the external `Select` has the styles applied they might have a higher specificity and are still overriding the styles you applied. (see [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) for a primer on how specificity works)

Without knowing which `Select` component you're using it's a bit hard to debug, but I'm assuming it uses inline styles (i.e. the `style` prop) which have a very high specificity and would thus override your applied styles.

There's two ways to bump specificity of your styles, both of which are **not recommended if the external component doesn't use inline styles**.

The first way to bump specificity is to use `!important`:

```
const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
  li {
    margin-left: 20px!important;
  }
`
```

In some cases that might not suffice, and it's also pretty tedious once you have more properties you need to forcibly override. A better way, but still not recommended  way too it is to use the class hack: (notice the ampersands)

```
const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
  &&& li {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
`
```

What `styled-components` does here is replace each of these `&` with the generated class, meaning the resulting CSS will look something like this:

```
.sc-asdf123.sc-asdf123.sc-asdf123 li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

These three classes massively bump the specificity of the styles within the block. That should do the trick!

---

To not style the first child you can use the `first-child` together with the `not` pseudo selector:

```
const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
  &&& li:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
`
```

Comment: Suggesting a hack or using specificity isn't a good direction to point someone in, imho.

Comment: If the external component uses inline styles, which I'm assuming is the case otherwise the styles would be overridden, there is no way to make your styles apply without giving them a higher specificity than the inline styles, and the only way to do that is sadly with hacks. Let me update my answer to explain why I think this is necessary, one second!

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect my assumptions (the external component uses inline styles) and explain why hacks are necessary but also that they shouldn't be used if not absolutely necessary. Does my answer make more sense to you now?

Comment: Absolutely! :-)

Comment: Although my issue was different, I will mark this as an answer to give me some good knowledge :). The issue I am facing is that on Click of the Select component, it opens a popover component, which has li tag. I wanted to override that li tag and I am not sure this is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS pseudo-classes:

```
const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
  li:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
`
```

Read more about CSS pseudo-classes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes